# How to filter responses from Amazon S3 ListObjectsV2Async-Method by LastModified-Property?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have more than 1000 (=max allowed) S3Objects in response by following request:

```
ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Prefix = prefix,
};

ListObjectsV2Response response = await s3client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);
```

How can i filter those request by LastModfied-Property?